# Interior product by a 1-form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-fields

I'm curretly working on this [reference](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Eruiloja/Math595/Spring14/book.pdf), where the interior product by a 1-form, denoted by $\iota_\alpha$, is defined  as: $$\iota_\alpha\theta(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{k-1})=\theta(\alpha,\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{k-1}), \ \ \ \theta\in\mathfrak{X}^k(M), \ \ \alpha_i\in\Omega^1(M), $$ where $M$ differentiable manifold.
This definition is very similar to that of the interior product by a vector field. However, I'm not entirely sure if I'm doing the math correctly.

First, given a point $x\in M$ and taking coordinates $\{x^1,\dots,x^n\}$, I think the following should be true: $$\theta(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k)(x)=\theta|_x(\alpha_1|_x,\dots,\alpha_k|_x)=\\\sum_{i_1<\dots<i_k}\theta^{i_1\dots i_k}(x)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i_1}}\right|_x\wedge\dots\wedge\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i_k}}\right|_x\left(\sum_i\alpha_{1,i}(x)dx^i|_x,\dots,\sum_i\alpha_{k,i}(x)dx^i|_x\right). $$ Is that correct? If so, it will be necessary to evaluate $\displaystyle \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right|_x\left(dx^j|_x\right) $, which I think would not be absurd because the vector space $T_xM$ is finite-dimensional and it would be correct to say that $\displaystyle \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right|_x\left(dx^j|_x\right) =dx^j|_x\left(\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right|_x\right)=\delta^j_i $. Is this also correct?

Finally, with $X\in\mathfrak{X}^1(M)$, $\alpha\in\Omega^1(M)$ and taking into account the usual definition of the interior product by a vector field, I think that $\iota_X\alpha=\iota_\alpha X$. I'm right?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, that seems about right; note that if you're more familiar with interior products of vector fields into forms, then this situation is almost the same thing, because of finite-dimensionality! Finite-dimensionality, as you suspected, of the vector spaces involved means we view vectors as elements of the double duals, and hence they can act on elements of the single dual.

Comment: Note also that for the purposes of calculation, the definition alone isn't the most efficient way of proceeding. It's better to prove some basic theorems about how interior products behave with respect to wedge-products (some sort of 'anti' product rule). Then, $\iota_{\alpha}(X^1\wedge\cdots\wedge X^k)=\sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^{i-1} X^1\wedge\cdots \wedge (\iota_{\alpha}X^i)\wedge \cdots \wedge X^k$, i.e you go one-by-one across the list $X^1\wedge\cdots\wedge X^k$, and starting with a $+$ sign, replace each $X^i$ by $(\iota_{\alpha}X^i)=\alpha(X^i)$ (a $0$-form), and alternate signs as you go along.

Comment: @peek-a-boo, thank you very much for the confirmation!